# Package as a zip file?

Tags: package-management

Can I download Ubuntu **packages** like `tar` and `gcc` as a zip files?  Anybody please explain me how to do, as I already tried, and I am not able find the solution.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do, considering this: 1) Ubuntu normally distributes packages using the `apt`/`deb` packaging system. 2) `zip` files are not a native Linux/Unix file format, but originally a format for [MS/Dos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP). 3) You can do whatever you want, as long as there is written instructions for it. 4) You can also distribute applications as `zip` files for Ubuntu, but I don't think many people will find this is a good idea. So please explain in detail, thanks.

Comment: You can download many packages as *zip* files, however there is no one standard for what's inside, thus how you deal with them will depend on how/why they exist in that format, how created, and how the packager intended you to use them... ie. package specific instructions are required. Downloads as .tar.gz/.tar.bz or just .zip usually have instructions/clues, but are non-standard (or follow pre-1990 standards) and are thus deprecated  (from the days of TAPE drives)

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot download a `.deb` package "as a zip file", as a `.deb` package is not "zipped". The `zip` file format is not native to GNU/Linux, and is often not used in favor of GNU/Linux native formats.

Yes, you can download or transmit a `.deb` package. A `.deb` package is simply a normal `.ar` archive. These archives can be opened using the `ar` command, or by normal Ubuntu Desktop tools like Archive Manager (aka `file-roller`). Ubuntu `.deb` packages are available from https://packages.ubuntu.com